# How to display two v-navigation-drawer next to each other and be able to hide the right one from the left one?

Tags: vuejs2, vuetify.js, v-navigation-drawer

With Vuetify I would like to display two `v-navigation-drawer`s next to each other and be able to hide the right one with a button within the left one. My current code (see below) displays the right drawer over the left one, but I want it to display right drawer next to the left one (see screens below).

I tried to find something useful in the official documentation and went through a few different sample templates but nothing was helpful in my case.

I was able to come up with the following code:

```html
<template>
  <v-app dark>
    <v-navigation-drawer v-model="leftMenu" app clipped>
      <v-container ma-0 pa-0>
        <v-toolbar flat>
          <span>Some helper toolbar</span>
        </v-toolbar>
      </v-container>

      <v-container pa-1 mt-1>
        <v-layout row wrap>
          <v-list>
            <v-list-tile>
              <v-list-tile-action>
                <span><a @click.stop="toggleRightMenu"><v-icon>android</v-icon> Task Menu</a></span>
              </v-list-tile-action>
            </v-list-tile>
            <v-list-tile>
              <v-list-tile-action>
                <span><v-icon>android</v-icon> Menu Element #1</span>
              </v-list-tile-action>
            </v-list-tile>
          </v-list>
        </v-layout>
      </v-container>
    </v-navigation-drawer>

    <v-navigation-drawer v-model="rightMenu" app clipped>
      <v-container>
        <v-layout>
          <v-list>
            <v-list-tile>
              <v-list-tile-action>
                <span><v-icon>android</v-icon> Testing...</span>
              </v-list-tile-action>
            </v-list-tile>
          </v-list>
        </v-layout>
      </v-container>
    </v-navigation-drawer>

    <v-toolbar app clipped-left>
      <v-toolbar-side-icon @click="leftMenu = !leftMenu"></v-toolbar-side-icon>
      <v-toolbar-title class="headline">
        <span>Testing...</span>
      </v-toolbar-title>
      <v-spacer></v-spacer>
    </v-toolbar>

    <v-content>
      <router-view/>
    </v-content>

    <v-footer app>
      <span>Footer</span>
    </v-footer>
  </v-app>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'App',
  data() {
    return {
      leftMenu: true,
      rightMenu: false
    }
  },
  methods: {
    toggleRightMenu() {
      this.rightMenu = !this.rightMenu;
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Currently I have the following: https://i.ibb.co/txdN0X8/current-drawer.png

I am looking for something like that: https://i.ibb.co/b514yyC/target-drawer.png

Comment: Instead of using screenshot picture (I'm assuming they are), can you please use codepen for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The trick is to have a `v-layout` that fills the height and contains both of the navigation drawers.

One more thing that you need to make sure to apply is to have a `z-index` on both navigation drawers. Otherwise, when you toggle the right nav it will go at the top of the left nav. And when you want to toggle the left nav you actually have to toggle both.

I have created a [Codepen](https://codepen.io/djshan/pen/PgddLd?editors=1010) using your data example.

```html
<v-toolbar flat>
  <v-toolbar-side-icon @click="toggleLeftMenu"></v-toolbar-side-icon>
  <v-toolbar-title class="headline">
    <span>Testing...</span>
  </v-toolbar-title>
  <v-spacer></v-spacer>
</v-toolbar>
<v-layout fill-height>
  <v-navigation-drawer
    style="z-index: 2"
    dark
    clipped
    stateless
    v-model="leftMenu"
  >
    <v-container ma-0 pa-0>
      <v-toolbar flat>
        <span>Some helper toolbar</span>
      </v-toolbar>
    </v-container>
    <v-list>
      <v-list-tile>
        <v-list-tile-action>
          <v-icon @click="rightMenu = !rightMenu">android</v-icon>
        </v-list-tile-action>
        <v-list-tile-content>
          <v-list-tile-title>Task Menu</v-list-tile-title>
        </v-list-tile-content>
      </v-list-tile>
      <v-list-tile>
        <v-list-tile-action>
          <v-icon>android</v-icon>
        </v-list-tile-action>
        <v-list-tile-content>
          <v-list-tile-title>Menu Element #1</v-list-tile-title>
        </v-list-tile-content>
      </v-list-tile>
    </v-list>
  </v-navigation-drawer>
  <v-navigation-drawer
    dark
    style="z-index: 1"
    v-model="rightMenu"
    class="pb-0"
    stateless
  >
    <v-list>
      <v-list-tile>
        <v-list-tile-action>
          <v-icon>android</v-icon>
        </v-list-tile-action>
        <v-list-tile-content>
          <v-list-tile-title>Testing right nav</v-list-tile-title>
        </v-list-tile-content>
      </v-list-tile>
    </v-list>
  </v-navigation-drawer>
</v-layout>
```

Hope it helps :)

Comment: Thanks, it looks good. The only problem I can see is that when the right menu is closed and I want to close the left one using `toggleLeftMenu`, the left menu is closed but the right menu pops up.

Comment: So when the right menu is closed and you close the left Menu what do you expect? just to see the right menu or close them both like https://codepen.io/djshan/pen/PgddLd

Comment: When the right menu is closed and I close the left one, then I would like both of them to be closed. I think this codepen.io/djshan/pen/PgddLd is the best solution. Thanks!

Comment: One more problem with the solution. When I want to add a content to the app, the content goes under the menus rather that right to the menus. See here: https://codepen.io/ratk/pen/mgzjoV?editors=1010

Comment: The problem is that when you have `fill-height` on your layout it will take the whole width. So your content goes to the next line. However, If you place the v-content inside the `v-layout` it will solve the problem.[see](https://codepen.io/djshan/pen/QPVoWG)

Comment: Displaying of the content works correctly, but now the handling of closing and opening of the menus doen't work as expected.

Comment: I tried every way I could think of. It does not work. I asked this question in Discord and I was told they do not support this right now. I am going to request this feature to be added to next versions.

Comment: Ok, I see. Anyway thanks for the effort and the notice!

Answer (score 0):

You could try achieve by having 2 navigation drawers.
The second one's `margin-left` should be equivalent to the first drawer.

Please take a look at this code pen. Hope this helps.

https://codepen.io/Jubels/pen/xeazYY?&editable=true&editors=101

```
<div id="app">
  <v-app id="inspire">
    <v-layout
      wrap
      style="height: 200px;"
    >
      <v-container>
        <v-layout justify-center>
          <v-btn
            color="pink"
            dark
            @click.stop="drawer = !drawer"
          >
            Toggle Drawer 1
          </v-btn>
          <v-btn
            color="pink"
            dark
            @click.stop="drawer2 = !drawer2"
          >
            Toggle Drawer 2
          </v-btn>
        </v-layout>
      </v-container>

      <v-navigation-drawer
        v-model="drawer"
        :mini-variant="mini"
        absolute
        dark
      >
        <v-list class="pa-1">
          <v-list-tile v-if="mini" @click.stop="mini = !mini">
            <v-list-tile-action>
              <v-icon>chevron_right</v-icon>
            </v-list-tile-action>
          </v-list-tile>

          <v-list-tile avatar tag="div">
            <v-list-tile-avatar>
              <img src="https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/men/85.jpg">
            </v-list-tile-avatar>

            <v-list-tile-content>
              <v-list-tile-title>John Leider</v-list-tile-title>
            </v-list-tile-content>

            <v-list-tile-action>
              <v-btn icon @click.stop="mini = !mini">
                <v-icon>chevron_left</v-icon>
              </v-btn>
            </v-list-tile-action>
          </v-list-tile>
        </v-list>

        <v-list class="pt-0" dense>
          <v-divider light></v-divider>

          <v-list-tile
            v-for="item in items"
            :key="item.title"
            @click=""
          >
            <v-list-tile-action>
              <v-icon>{{ item.icon }}</v-icon>
            </v-list-tile-action>

            <v-list-tile-content>
              <v-list-tile-title>{{ item.title }}</v-list-tile-title>
            </v-list-tile-content>
          </v-list-tile>
        </v-list>
      </v-navigation-drawer>
      <v-navigation-drawer :style="`margin-left: ${drawer ? '300px' :  '0'}`"
        v-model="drawer2"
        :mini-variant="mini"
        absolute
        dark
      >
        <v-list class="pa-1">
          <v-list-tile v-if="mini" @click.stop="mini = !mini">
            <v-list-tile-action>
              <v-icon>chevron_right</v-icon>
            </v-list-tile-action>
          </v-list-tile>

          <v-list-tile avatar tag="div">
            <v-list-tile-avatar>
              <img src="https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/men/85.jpg">
            </v-list-tile-avatar>

            <v-list-tile-content>
              <v-list-tile-title>John Leider</v-list-tile-title>
            </v-list-tile-content>

            <v-list-tile-action>
              <v-btn icon @click.stop="mini = !mini">
                <v-icon>chevron_left</v-icon>
              </v-btn>
            </v-list-tile-action>
          </v-list-tile>
        </v-list>

        <v-list class="pt-0" dense>
          <v-divider light></v-divider>

          <v-list-tile
            v-for="item in items"
            :key="item.title"
            @click=""
          >
            <v-list-tile-action>
              <v-icon>{{ item.icon }}</v-icon>
            </v-list-tile-action>

            <v-list-tile-content>
              <v-list-tile-title>{{ item.title }}</v-list-tile-title>
            </v-list-tile-content>
          </v-list-tile>
        </v-list>
      </v-navigation-drawer>
    </v-layout>
  </v-app>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I think it's OK but there is small problem with it. When you click on the arrow to minimize the menu, the menu is minimized but it stays where it was before. I think this is a sign of bigger problem with solutions depending on manual handling of elements' width.

Comment: width is an actual prop of the navigation-drawer, so it is quite is to listen to it.

Answer (score 0):

I made it like bitbucket design, one is fixed (mini-variant) and the other one is a drawer
https://codepen.io/admica/pen/PoozMNw?editors=1010

```html
<div id="app">
  <v-app id="inspire">
    <v-navigation-drawer
      
      
       mini-variant
            mini-variant-width="56"
                         app
                         clipped
                         
          
            
    >
      <v-list dense>
        <v-list-item
          v-for="item in items"
          :key="item.text"
          @click=""
        >
          <v-list-item-action>
            <v-icon>{{ item.icon }}</v-icon>
          </v-list-item-action>
          <v-list-item-content>
            <v-list-item-title>
              {{ item.text }}
            </v-list-item-title>
          </v-list-item-content>
        </v-list-item>
        <v-subheader class="mt-3 grey--text text--darken-1">SUBSCRIPTIONS</v-subheader>
        <v-list>
          <v-list-item
            v-for="item in items2"
            :key="item.text"
            @click=""
          >
            <v-list-item-avatar>
              <img
                :src="`https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/men/${item.picture}.jpg`"
                alt=""
              >
            </v-list-item-avatar>
            <v-list-item-title v-text="item.text"></v-list-item-title>
          </v-list-item>
        </v-list>
        <v-list-item
          class="mt-3"
          @click=""
        >
          <v-list-item-action>
            <v-icon color="grey darken-1">add_circle_outline</v-icon>
          </v-list-item-action>
          <v-list-item-title class="grey--text text--darken-1">Browse Channels</v-list-item-title>
        </v-list-item>
        <v-list-item @click="">
          <v-list-item-action>
            <v-icon color="grey darken-1">settings</v-icon>
          </v-list-item-action>
          <v-list-item-title class="grey--text text--darken-1">Manage Subscriptions</v-list-item-title>
        </v-list-item>
      </v-list>
      
      
     
    </v-navigation-drawer>
     
     

    <v-app-bar
      app
      
      color="red"
      dense
    >
      <v-app-bar-nav-icon @click.stop="drawer = !drawer"></v-app-bar-nav-icon>
      <v-icon class="mx-3">fab fa-youtube</v-icon>
      <v-toolbar-title class="mr-5 align-center">
        <span class="title">Youtube</span>
      </v-toolbar-title>
      <v-spacer></v-spacer>
      <v-layout
        row
        align-center
        style="max-width: 650px"
      >
        <v-text-field
          :append-icon-cb="() => {}"
          placeholder="Search..."
          single-line
          append-icon="search"
          color="white"
          hide-details
        ></v-text-field>
      </v-layout>
    </v-app-bar>

    <v-content>
      
      <v-container fluid fill-height>
        <v-layout
          
          align-center
          style="position:relative"
        >
          <v-navigation-drawer
        v-model="drawer"
        
        v-if="drawer"
        
        
        
        
        
                          
        
        
      >
        <v-list-item>
          <v-list-item-avatar>
            <v-img src="https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/men/78.jpg"></v-img>
          </v-list-item-avatar>
  
          <v-list-item-content>
            <v-list-item-title>John Leider</v-list-item-title>
          </v-list-item-content>
        </v-list-item>
  
        <v-divider></v-divider>
  
        <v-list dense>
  
          <v-list-item
            v-for="item in items"
            :key="item.title"
            link
          >
            <v-list-item-icon>
              <v-icon>{{ item.icon }}</v-icon>
            </v-list-item-icon>
  
            <v-list-item-content>
              <v-list-item-title>{{ item.title }}</v-list-item-title>
            </v-list-item-content>
          </v-list-item>
        </v-list>
      </v-navigation-drawer>
          ahmed ali 
        </v-layout>
      </v-container>
    </v-content>
  </v-app>
</div>
```